# How to call Dapr Actor running on AKS from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks, dapr

We have some Dapr Actors running on an AKS cluster and a ASP.NET Core Based REST Api running on Azure App Service.

Is it possible to call an actor method of an actor in the AKS cluster from our REST Api running on Azure App Service without dapr Sidecar available?

Is it possible / required to setup the DNS Name of the AKS cluster so that Dapr can find the appropriate Actor?